# Why am I getting NoMethodError from IRB for my own Module and method

Tags: ruby, methods

I have taken this example *exactly* from the Ruby Cookbook.  Unfortunately for me, like a whole lot of the examples in that book, this one does not work:

my file (Find.rb - saved both locally and to Ruby\bin):

```
require 'find'

    module Find
     def match(*paths)
      matched=[]
      find(*paths) { |path| matched << path if yield path }
      return matched
     end
     module_function :match
    end
```

I try to call it this way from IRB, according to the example the book provides:

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'Find'
=> false

irb(main):003:0> Find.match("./") { |p| ext = p[-4...p.size]; ext && ext.downcase == "mp3" }
```

It SHOULD return a list of mp3 files in my recursive directory.  Instead, it does this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for Find:Module
        from (irb):3
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

What gives?  I'm new at this (although I MUST say that I'm farther along with Python, and much better at it!).

How can I get IRB to use my method?

Comment: Why would you name your library EXACTLY THE SAME NAME as another library except for the case of the first letter? find vs Find. If you're running  in windows you can probably expect trouble from this. Don't be ridiculous and rename your file to something other than 'Find' and try again.

Comment: Because that's what the example in Ruby Cookbook said!  Didn't invent it myself.  But I'll do what you suggest, thanks!

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. Here's what I changed:

Comment: Basically I changed library name to Froop and called it like so:

Comment: irb(main):016:0> Froop.match("./") { |p| ext = p[-4...p.size]; ext && ext.downcase == "mp3" }
NameError: uninitialized constant Object::Froop
        from (irb):16
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

Comment: How come I can't put coherent code samples into this forum?

Comment: A Question&Answer website. The comment form is *intentionally* crippled to discourage discussion, because a discussion is neither a question nor an answer. If you want to discuss something, go to a forum.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this with irb on a Mac running Snow Leopard while using the default version of ruby (and irb of course) installed with OS X.  I was able to get past it by including the module in IRB after loading the module or in the file after the module definition.

```
include module_name
```

I'm not sure if this is a defect or known behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation is that the code you posted is not the code you are running, since both carefully reading it and simply cut&paste&running it shows absolutely no problems whatsoever.

Comment: But the code I pasted IS the code I'm running.  Please tell me how can I pass my block to my code?

Comment: Hell with it.  I'll use Python.

Comment: @Rijksband: I just realized that you are on Windows. Windows doesn't distinguish between uppercase and lowercase filenames, so there could potentially be a problem. In fact, if you look at your IRb session above, you can see that `require 'Find'` returns `false`. A return value of `false` means that the library didn't need to be loaded because it was already loaded. Except that in this case, the library that was loaded was `find` not `Find`. So, it's correct: the method *is* undefined, because the file that defines it was never loaded in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that has been the problem all along.   How do I get around it and get my Block to call my code?

Comment: Please note that, as per my earlier comments, I changed both the name of the function and the name of the file (Froop).  Still I get this error:

Comment: irb(main):016:0> Froop.match("./") { |p| ext = p[-4...p.size]; ext && ext.downcase == "mp3" } NameError: uninitialized constant Object::Froop from (irb):16 from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

Comment: I can add my Froop.match statement to the end of my .rb and just execute it from cmd.  Doesn't work either:

Comment: E:\Sounds\Digital>ruby Froop.rb
Froop.rb:6:in `match': undefined method `find' for Froop:Module (NoMethodError)
        from Froop.rb:12:in `<main>'

E:\Sounds\Digital>ruby Froop.rb
Froop.rb:6:in `match': undefined method `find' for Froop:Module (NoMethodError)
        from Froop.rb:12:in `<main>'

Comment: You know guys, it's a been a very long day and I might be missing some things.  

Usually I use Python and don't get stuck on things like this for as long as I have in this case.   

I do appreciate your suggestions but this just isn't working I'm afraid.

So thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What directory are you calling IRB from? Try calling it from the directory where your `find.rb` file is located. Also, I don't know if it makes any difference but convention is to name the file the lowercase version of the module / class. So the module would be `Find` and the file name would be `find.rb`. You shouldn't need the `require` call in the file itself.

So, start your command prompt window, cd into the directory that contains `find.rb` and run `irb`. In IRB you should be able to `require "find"` and it should return true. From there you should be able to call `Find.match`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already 3 years old, but since this is the first hit on google for the problem, and I had been banging my head against the wall all afternoon with the same problem doing the tutorial here: http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex25.html, here goes: the function definition in the module should read

```
module Find
  def Find.match(*paths)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: `self.match` is preferable to `Find.match`, simply because it does not duplicate the name.